# What is a DeprecationDict()?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, warnings

I've run the following code on the MNIST dataset:

```
knn_2 = KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='euclidean',
           metric_params=None, n_jobs=None, n_neighbors=3, p=2,
           weights='distance')
knn_2.fit(X_train_small,y_train_small)
knn_cv = cross_validate(knn_2, X_train_small, y_train_small, cv=3, scoring='accuracy')
knn_cv['test_score'].mean()
```

(This model is terrible, by the way.)

When I was trying to figure out how to access the data from `cross_validate()`, I typed `knn_cv.mean()`, which gave me the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-2f23e50adc56> in <module>()
      4 knn_2.fit(X_train_small,y_train_small)
      5 knn_cv = cross_validate(knn_2, X_train_small, y_train_small, cv=3, scoring='accuracy')
----> 6 knn_cv.mean()

AttributeError: 'DeprecationDict' object has no attribute 'mean'
```

I did some searching and discovered the following [repo](https://gist.github.com/jnothman/d04dd9ae2ef4faf7914b0d9431ad62d6), which describes `DeprecationDict()` in the docstring as "A dict which raises a warning when some keys are looked up."

Can someone explains what that means, and what `DeprecationDict()` actually does? That sounds like the equivalent of "A function that doesn't work if nonsensical args are passed."

Comment: Based on how the code looks and the comments in the code, I believe `DeprecationDict` is a way sklearn marks thing as deprecated. Instead of deleting the deprecated code or putting deprecated warnings all over the place, they wrap it in a `DeprecationDict` and if you try to `get` and attribute it will throw the error. In other words I believe it is telling you that  whatever type of object `knn_cv` is, it is a deprecated object for that particular version of sklearn.  So its telling you that `knn_cv` is a deprecated object and thus you can't use `mean` on it. Just an educated guess though.

Answer (score 1):

**Upgrade your `sklearn` installation.**

Working example:

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data[:150]
y = diabetes.target[:150]
lasso = linear_model.Lasso()

cv_results = cross_validate(lasso, X, y, cv=3)
cv_results['test_score'].mean()
#0.14901602799979097

sklearn.__version__
'0.20.4'
```